# why does Qt Designer creates extra unnecessary waste code in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I've created a simple form (without any functionality) which includes 2 widgets (a Push button and a LineEdit) first by manual coding then by using Qt Designer. I don't understand why Qt Designer creates so many extra codes that seem to be useless (to me) and makes it so complicated!.
This is the code i've written manually:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QPushButton,QApplication, QLineEdit

class Example(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.initUI()
        def initUI(self):

            btn1 = QPushButton('Button1', self)
            btn1.move(30,50)
            btn1.resize(btn1.sizeHint())
            le = QLineEdit(self)
            le.move(100,100)
            self.setGeometry(300,300,290,150)
            self.setWindowTitle('Event Sender')
            self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is the output of Qt Designer UI file (as a python file)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(417, 297)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 130, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 180, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 417, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Event Sender"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button1"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here are my Questions:

1. Can some one please explain to me what is going on with the Qt Designer created file?
   It seems to me that it creates a seperate class just for the UI and then creates an instance of the `QMainWindow` class and then modifies this instance within the `Ui_MainWindow()` created instance.
   But in my code, i directly created a MainWindow class which inherits from QMainWindow and then set the UI up within that class
2. Also what's the point of passing our `QMainWindow` instance here??: `self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)` Why not `self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()`?
3. What is the point of these many extra code?!

Answer (score 2):

1. In Qt/C++ uic is a tool that allows you to convert a .ui to C++ code as an interface used to fill in some widget, that same concept is what pyuic tries to do, but in python. In your case fill in a QMainWindow or a class derived from it. But if the inheritance is implemented directly then it would be limited to the functionality that I initially thought about since, for example, it could not be used by a class inherited from QMainWidow. In conclusion: pyuic imitates what uic does, and uic aims to create an interface that fills in some Qt Widget.
2. Both forms are equivalent and valid so there is no better way (that is totally debatable)
3. Following that of (1) uic adds more things to handle the QObjects through the MOC such as the objectName(), it also implements a template for you to do translations (your application can be shown in different languages), in addition to using QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName() that allows automatic connections.

If you are going to use pyuic then do not pay attention to that code since you are not going to need to modify it, if you consider that it is unnecessary code then do not use it. Like any tool you have its pros and cons. If you consider that the implementation could improve then you could build your own tool that reads the .ui (which is an XML) and according to that information implement the code generation.

Comment: Ok so `self.centralwidget` is the link between the mainwindow and our UI? also instead of passing in `self.centralwidget` to each widget that we create, we could have done this: `self.centralwidget.setLayout(verticalLayout)`, Correct?

Comment: @Sherafati Do you know what `foo_widget = FooWidget(another_widget)` implies? That indicates that foo_widget is currently the child of another_widget and therefore renders within another_widget. And that's what happens with pushButton and lineEdit regarding centralwidget Instead, your custom code is QMainWindow's children. On the other hand, the codes you provide are not equivalent, I recommend adding dockwidgets so you can see what the objective of centralwidget is, also read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework

Comment: @Sherafati My recommendation: According to what you write you don't like the code generated by QtDesigner so why do you use it? If you don't like a tool then don't use it :-) and create your own tool, and you will understand what each element of pyuic implies

Comment: what is the point of defining and setting a centralwidget for our QMainWindow? The only time that i think it makes sense is when we want to add a layout to our window, otherwise it will be the same result.